# Soundcloud custom widget using Sound Manager for mobile

Tags: javascript, audio, mobile, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I am currently working on a project for a DJ friend who would like to have music playing on his website. I am looking to do this by using Sound Manager 2 connected to Soundcloud. I have made a really quick prototype of this which I have put online here: http://www.jackyoungcreative.com/slopeside/index.html

I am having 3 problems with this:

1 - When opening on a mobile phone and clicking play nothing happens (no sound plays and button doesn't change to pause)

2 - On the desktop version I want the music to play automatically once the page has loaded

3 - Each time the user opens the page I want a different song to play and for the songs to then play randomly from there (shuffle)

ANY help would be hugely appreciated. If you would like me to post my code just let me know. I am pretty novice when it comes to coding but really keen to learn so please do excuse any basic questions I may ask!

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding "href='#'" to your play-button link, maybe click doesnt fire because of that on mobile (if you do that, be sure to prevent default action with `event.preventDefault()` within event handler
2. You could dispatch click event on play buttton at the point where your application has finished initialising (this won't work on mobile 100%, you need user interaction to initalise 
   media playback there)
3. You have the tracks in `playlist.tracks` after you issue API request, you can [shuffle the array at this point](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&safe=off&q=shuffle%20array%20javascript)